# DB2 creating a random but unique character identifier upon row insert

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I currently have a column in a DB2 table which is being passed through web calls and procedure by a character-encrypted value. It is type CHARACTER(13) with a CSSID for encryption.

This has become a huge pain to accommodate through multiple APIs but was initially intended to allow us a unique ID to use in calls that wasn't the primary key.

In DB2-400, what would be the next best thing as far as a 13 or more character string that is unique and randomly created upon insert, but doesn't require decryption (just a plain string)?

Is there a commonly-gravitated-to method for this? We aren't passing secure data, so there's no need for encryption, but we just want a randomly created and unique character

Comment: Guaranteeing uniqueness is a lot of work.  Use the primary key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could I just have a column that essentially mirrors the primary key as far as incrementing and record creation? But maybe incrementing by 5 instead of 1

Comment: I don't know what the primary key looks like, but there are lots of options for obfuscating something when you know its type -- jumbling a string, re-mapping characters, arithmetic computations on a number.

Comment: Currently it's just an integer incremented by 1

Comment: Can't you use a SEQUENCE? It's not random, but it's unique.

Comment: @TheImpaler how do I apply that to an existing column in DB2 though? that would be fine, I need the uniqueness more than the randomness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `hex(generate_unique())`. It's unique `CHAR(26)` string.
Or `to_char(timestamp(generate_unique()), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF6')`. You may play with format of the [to_char](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzscavarcharformat.htm) function as well. May be useful to use, let's say, reverse format like `FF6SSMIHH24DDMMYYYY` to avoid unique index page contention upon heavy insert activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section.

I don't have access to a DB2-400 (anymore), but I tested the code below in DB2 10.5 for Linux.

```
create sequence seq1;

select concat('A', varchar_format(next value for seq1, '000000000000')) as my_id
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Result, if you run it 4 times in a row:

```
A0000000000001
A0000000000002
A0000000000003
A0000000000004
```

Maybe there's something equivalent in DB2-400.

Comment: so in a procedure I could do the Create statement, then ```insert into table (sequence_col) values(select concat('A', varchar_format(next value for seq1, '000000000000')) as sequence_col
from sysibm.sysdummy1)

Comment: That should work. You probably want to drop the sequence at the end (even under error conditions).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be using `GENERATE_UNIQUE()`

> GENERATE_UNIQUE function returns a bit data character string 13 bytes
>   long (CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA)

Doesn't really have anything to do with encryption...

And pretty much the ideal solution in my opinion generating a unique value other than a simple numeric identity.  So what the problem you are having?